# BigQuery - Cannot join on repeated field

Tags: google-bigquery

Im trying to create a table that is 1 column with each row being a new date between 2 separate dates. The query works fine until I add a where clause that contains a subquery ie. NOT IN (SELECT ....). It works fine if I do something like NOT IN (TIMESTAMP('xyz')).

I keep getting an error saying "Cannot join on repeated field t2.f0__group.SomeDate"

I have no clue why this is happening. Also Im fairly new to BQ so if there is an easier way to do this please let me know. Thanks

```
SELECT SomeDate FROM
(
  SELECT DATE_ADD(Day, i, "DAY") SomeDate
  FROM
  (
    SELECT '2020-01-03' Day
  ) T1
  CROSS JOIN
  (
    SELECT
     POSITION(
       SPLIT(
         RPAD('', DATEDIFF('2020-01-30','2020-01-03') * 2, 'a,'))) i 
    FROM
    (
      SELECT NULL
    )
  ) T2
)
WHERE SomeDate NOT IN (SELECT OtherDate FROM 
  (
    SELECT TIMESTAMP('2020-01-04 00:00:00 UTC') AS OtherDate
  ),
  (
    SELECT TIMESTAMP('2020-01-06 00:00:00 UTC') AS OtherDate
  ),
  (
    SELECT TIMESTAMP('2020-01-08 00:00:00 UTC') AS OtherDate
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to start over from scratch using below example
I think it does exactly what you are trying to achieve with probably minor adjustments

```
SELECT SomeDate
FROM (
  SELECT 
    DATE(DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP('2020-01-03'), pos - 1, "DAY")) AS SomeDate
  FROM (
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS pos, *
     FROM (FLATTEN((
       SELECT SPLIT(RPAD('', 1 + DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMP('2020-01-30'), TIMESTAMP('2020-01-03')), '.'),'') AS h
       FROM (SELECT NULL)),h
    ))
  )
) a
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT OtherDate FROM
    (SELECT '2020-01-04' AS OtherDate),
    (SELECT '2020-01-06' AS OtherDate),
    (SELECT '2020-01-08' AS OtherDate)
) b
ON b.OtherDate = a.SomeDate
WHERE b.OtherDate IS NULL
```